# How can I open a page with json content and put it in a variable

Tags: discord.js

Ok, like the title i don't know i can do this.
I have to open a url where there is json code and store it in a variable.
I tried this way that I found here:

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  let url = "my link"
  snekfetch.get(url).then(r => 
  message.channel.send(decodeURIComponent(r.body)));
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Now I tried this code:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
fetch(userUrl)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));
};
```

And I got this:
[console log](https://www.pastiebin.com/5d9467bdc8c61)

How can I i take those object and store them value in an variable?

I've solved it:
The function

```
async function takeXpVerification(userUrl){
    return await fetch(userUrl)
    .then(res => res.json())
}
```

Where i call it for get the value

```
getAfterCurrentXp = await takeXpVerification(userUrl);
getAfterCurrentXp = getAfterCurrentXp["profile"]["experience"];
```

Comment: You already have the object in the `json` variable. I guess what you actually want is to return the result of your request synchronously which is not possible (the way I assume you want to to work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I want to take the value of one of this json in a var

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want a subset of the json ? In your code, the `json` variable that you are logging is the variable that has the value you are asking for.

Comment: I want to put in a variable this value experience: 621091, and how can i access to the other object?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `snekfetch` package is deprecated, use `node-fetch` or `Axios`,

example with Axios:

`npm i axios`

```
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  const res = await axios.get('URL HERE')
  message.channel.send(res.data);
}
```

Comment: `console.log(res.data)` right above `message.channel.send` and send response from console here.